# Command line tool for receiveing file via bluetooth in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, bluetooth, obex

Is there any command line tool for receiving a file in Windows using Bluetooth OPP profile?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You will have better luck asking on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. the CmdlineRunner app in Brecham.Obex's server-side library samples.
http://inthehand.co.uk/files/folders/objectexchange/default.aspx "Brecham ObexServer r6"

Comment: Do you have any working link?I have been looking around but not a clue where can i download this ObexServer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would might work:
http://forkbeard.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId111209

Comment: Thanks Buzznfrog, But this tool acts as obex client to pull/push a file from/to a obex server. I want a command line server tool which will receive these requests.

Answer (score 0):

Also see http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/

I haven't tried this software yet, but planning to when I receive some BT dongles next week.